# Data-table only displaying truthy value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am currently working with AgReact table to display data from my endpoints. The data-table is fine but it is not displaying false values from the endpoints on the table.
These are my codes below

State

```
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
```

Column Definitions

```
 const [columnDefs] = useState([
{ field: 'id', headerClass: 'header-red', editable: false, tooltipField: 'name' },
{ field: 'name', headerClass: 'header-red', tooltipField: 'name' },
{ field: 'active', headerClass: 'header-red', tooltipField: 'name' }])
```

useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
  getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
  axios(apiUrl).then(res => {
  setTableData(res.data);
});
```

};

JSX

```
 <AgGridReact
        rowData={tableData}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        pagination={true}
        paginationPageSize={12}
        enableBrowserTooltips={true}
      ></AgGridReact>
```

Also see the values from my endpoint and see it is also logging false on the console.      [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `tableData` and change boolean `true`, `false` to string and then feed that data to the component.

```
const getData = () => {
  axios(apiUrl).then(res => {
  res?.data.forEach(n=>n.active = n?.active?.toString() || '');
  setTableData(res.data);
});
```

Comment: Pls can you explain further, I don't get it.

Comment: you might be getting `tableData` from an api, which has `active` key. Whenever you receive the response, you need to loop through that data and convert those true/false values to string.

Comment: It will be better if you showed me in codes. I don't even have an idea on where to edit

Comment: If you add your code where you are fetching the data from api, i can help.

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: I tried it. I am getting error of  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')

Comment: Yes, handled that case as well. check now, else lets move to chat.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your time and efforts